# How to get the function and module names from a traceback?

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract info from a traceback, but I'm getting errors.

I want to get rid of the `call` variable in the following example code. I want to search the traceback and get the name of the called socket module function. How can I do this?

```
try:
    sock = None
    call = "socket"
    sock = socket.socket(family, stype)
    call = "setsockopt"
    set_my_options():
    call = "connect"
    sock.connect(addr)
except OSError as err:
    if sock is not None:
        sock.close()
    # call = name of the failed socket.XXX() call
    raise RPCError("{} failed".format(call))
```

I have tried to begin with (Python3 only):

```
stack = traceback.extract_stack(err.__traceback__)
```

or (Python2 and Python3)

```
stack = traceback.extract_stack(sys.exc_info()[2])
```

but got:

> AttributeError: 'traceback' object has no attribute 'f_lineno'

---

**Edit1**:

After fixing the overlooked error, this is what I have now:

```
    ....
except OSError as err:
    tb = traceback.extract_tb(err.__traceback__)
    for tb_entry in reversed(tb):
        if tb_entry[0] == __file__:
            failed = tb_entry[3]
            break
    ....
```

It extracts the last traceback entry where the executed code was still in the current file. Internals of a foreign module would not be very helpfull. The result is a line of code, e.g. `sock.connect(addr)`. Not exactly what I wanted, but close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this way you can retrieve the function name and the module name where the function is.

```
import traceback

def func():
    try:
        # My code
    except Exception as e:
        stack = traceback.extract_stack()
        (filename, line, procname, text) = stack[-1]
        print procname # function name
        print filename # module name
```

Comment: I see it now: I confused `extract_tb` and `extract_stack`. The former takes tb argument, but the latter does not.

Comment: That's not really the module name though. A module name is in the form "foo.bar", not a full path.